# Detect the internet connection

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6

How to detect if there is an internet connection on windows mobile 6 phone? What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy to implement yourself. I found it easier to use the [ConnectionManager](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/c37633a6-489a-c906-a691-91bd3cca8378.htm) class from the [OpenNetCF Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=65).